# Allowing players to create or upgrade their weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, crafting

I'm DMing a Pathfinder game with all new characters and I'm not very experienced as well. We are all learning a lot each session and the players are happy to change things when we learn we've been breaking rules.

Anyway, I have one player (dwarf barbarian) that has been adding teeth, horns and other pointy animal-parts from their quarries to his greatclub. So far I've allowed him to treat his greatclub as bludgeon and piercing damage, and after adding so many, we are now treating his weapon as masterwork.

He's very attached to his club and I know as we progress, he'll prefer to continually upgrade it as opposed to replacing it. **What are some ways he can continue to upgrade his weapon that won't end the weapon's progression?** Our cleric is getting the Craft Magic Arms and Armor feat at his next level, and the party has been talking about enchanting things but from what I've read so far enchants seem more on the permanent end (I'm totally fine with being wrong).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "won't end the weapon's progression"? Do you simply mean the weapon will stay useful for the character?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to enchant an item [after it has been created](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Adding-New-Abilities) so there isn't any issue with them enchanting the hammer.

Using the [Magic weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/) value chart you can determine the price they need to pay to enchant the item. The first enchantment, let's assume they put +2 enhancement bonus on the weapon, the cost would be 8000 gold, 4000 if the Cleric crafts it.

Now later on, let's say they want to increase the enhancement bonus to +4. The cost for that would be 32,000 gold minus the 8000 they already paid. so 24,000, again half that if the Cleric is the one enchanting it.

Adding abilities and such works the same, If instead of increasing the enhancement bonus to +4 he wanted to add [Holy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy/) to the weapon it would be the same, as Holy is worth a +2 bonus.

Now you should be a bit careful with this, remember they might only be paying half the cost of these weapons but if you are tracking their [Wealth Per Level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/) they should be counted as full market cost. They get a large boon being able to pick and choose their own custom enchantments. I only add this as I have personal experience with a character group getting quite overpowered when our new GM, they were new to GMing as well, counted the cost of the enchanted weapons as half cause we crafted them. We wound up able to get so much equipment that we were stronger than our level making it hard for them to craft CR appropriate fights for us.

This is of course only my own experience so it might be different for you.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the weapon's hard bonus is capped at +5, and the total bonus value cap of all properties is +10, so there is a limit on when the weapon's "progression" stops -- that is, when it becomes a *+5 deadly anarchic wounding greatclub*.

Answer (score 1):

Magical items are not immutable, especially not magic weapons and armour. You can always add new enchantments or upgrades to an existing magical item unless it's an artifact or similar. [Mechanically](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Upgrading-Items), this is treated as creating a magical item with a value equal to the finished item's cost minus the original item's cost, so:

+1 weapon: 2000gp

+2 weapon: 8000gp

+1 weapon to +2 weapon: 8000-2000=6000gp

Of course the cost of creating a magical item yourself is half whatever it would cost to buy, so your cleric could upgrade a +1 weapon to a +2 weapon for a base cost of 3000gp. Presumably he'd provide this service at cost for his comrades, though I have been in games where the artificer liked to levy a small fee for his services to party members - it was cheaper than going to market, but he made a profit on it.

It's normal for players to get attached to weapons which have served them particularly well, or for characters to have weapons that have backstory significance, like an ancestral sword - the rules support magically upgrading them over time so they remain useful as the character levels.